# Middleware for checking if resource is owned by user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having some trouble making middleware that checks if the user owns the resource being requested.

For example, if the user goes to `/playlists/1/edit`, and they do not own playlist 1, it should display a 401 error.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class CheckOwnership {

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Playlist::find($request->route()->parameters()['playlists'])->user_id !== $request->user()->id)
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

This is terrible and only works for the Playlist resource, but I can't find any better way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with the newly added Form Request Validation.

You can see it in detail here (Authorizing Form Requests):
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

The example given is actually about a user attempting to edit a comment they own.

Extract:

> The form request class also contains an authorize method. Within this
>   method, you may check if the authenticated user actually has the
>   authority to update a given resource. For example, if a user is
>   attempting to update a blog post comment, do they actually own that
>   comment?

In your case, simply return false from the authorize method if they do no own the Playlist.

Comment: I thought these were only for validating forms? Can they be used with GET requests?

Comment: They can still be used for GET requests because forms can be submitted to a GET path.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Laravel 5 does not support passing parameters to middlewares. I use sessions instead.

On your playlist controller, fetch the owner of the playlist and store it on a session. Let's say you have a playlists table with columns userID and playlistID.

```
public function __construct($playlistID){
    $owner = Playlist::where('playlistID',$playlistID)->pluck('userID');
    Session::put('OWNER',$owner);
    $this->middleware('CheckOwnership',['only'=>'edit']); // apply it to edit function only, assuming you are using a route resource
}
```

Then, simply retrieve it on your middleware handle function.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::get('OWNER') != $request->user()->id)
    {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So far, this is a simple workaround. We have to wait till Otwell considers filter-like middlewares. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For those using Laravel 8, I recommend using using [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies). This would let you organize authorization logic for specific models (e.x. the Playlist model for @ntzm).

So for example, a PlaylistPolicy class can be generated,

```
php artisan make:policy PlaylistPolicy --model=Playlist
```

and then the `update` function could look like this.

```
public function update(User $user, Playlist $playlist)
{
    return $user->id === $playlist->user_id;
}
```

There are multiple way of enforcing this policy. If you would like to use middleware, Laravel has the `can` middleware that can enforce policies, so new middleware won't need to be written. In your route file this would look something like this,

```
Route::put('playlists/{playlist}/edit', ...)
    ->middleware(['can:update,playlist']);
```

Note: If the `--model` option isn't used, the policy will have to be [registered](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#registering-policies) manually, and example policy methods won't be automatically generated.